# Parse.com REST API - Special Characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, special-characters, parse-platform

Through [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) REST API i'm signing in user with their Facebook accounts in node.js. I get an error when I try to sign up users that have names such as `Martin Sánchez`. Are special characters something to be aware of when saving objects in Parse.com through the REST API?

Note:
I'm encountering this problem only on the REST API, meaning that it works fine in iOS and Android.
I tried encoding the string but it gets saved literally(`Martin S\\u00e1nchez` as a string).

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your request as UTF-8. Are you sure you aren't sending Latin-1 encoded data?

Comment: Also, have you considered using the official Parse JavaScript SDK in node instead of reinventing the wheel with REST?

Comment: I didn't know about the npm package until a week ago, i wanted to kill myself.